# How to check if bash command executed correctly?

Tags: c++, bash

I am writing a program that outputs certain system information, think of it like my own neofetch. I am now at the point where i want to get the package manager used in the users system. Since there is no universal method to either grab the package manager or grab the amount of installed packages ive come up with an idea. My idea to do that is that i have an array of bash commands for every package manager running in a for loop, which, if run on a machine with the right package manager returns exit code 0 after running `echo $?` . after that it uses the right command to output the amount of packages installed.
However it seems that running bash commands with either `system()` or another method i found online doesnt seem to affect the `$?` value.

Following is the code:

```
#include "iostream"
#include "array"
#include "bits/stdc++.h"
using namespace std;

// this is the method i found online on geeksforgeeks
string GetStdoutFromCommand(string cmd) {

  string data;
  FILE * stream;
  const int max_buffer = 256;
  char buffer[max_buffer];
  cmd.append(" 2>&1");

  stream = popen(cmd.c_str(), "r");

  if (stream) {
    while (!feof(stream))
      if (fgets(buffer, max_buffer, stream) != NULL) data.append(buffer);
    pclose(stream);
  }
  return data;
}

string getPkgMngr() {
  // List of PckMngrs (in order):
  // I took the commands from rxfetch, since i dont have all the systems installed.
  // pckMngr is used to get exit codes 0< . Without this the for loop wont work, since wc -l always returns 0, even on systems where the given packagemanager doesn't exist. 
  string pckMngr[8] = {"apt-get -h",
                      "pacman -h",
                      "nix-env --help",
                      "xbps-query -h",
                      "apk stats",
                      "dnf help",
                      "rpm --help",
                      "emerge -h"
  };
  system("fgfgfgfg");  //test output
  cout << system("echo $?") << endl;  //test output

  string pckMngrList[8] = {"echo $(($(apt list --installed 2>/dev/null | wc -l) - 1))", //apt
                      "pacman -Q | wc -l", //pacman
                      "nix-env -qa --installed '*' | wc -l", //nix
                      "xbps-query -l | wc -l", //xbps
                      "apk search | wc -l", //apk
                      "dnf list installed | wc -l", //dnf
                      "rpm -qa | wc -l", //rpm
                      "qlist -I | wc -l" //emerge
  };
  int amountPckMngr = sizeof(pckMngr)/sizeof(*pckMngr); //get array size

  for(int i=1; i < amountPckMngr - 1; i++) {
    string pckMngr_Cmd_Str = pckMngr[i]; //convert string to const char
    const char * pckMngr_Cmd_Char = pckMngr_Cmd_Str.c_str();

    if(system("echo $?") == 0) { //if exit code is 0 (aka command ran successfully, aka this is package manager)
      cout << i;
      return pckMngrList[i];            //return correct command to get number of installed packages
    } else {
      return "Couldn't determine package manager!"; //else return we couldnt find pck mngr
    }
  }
  return "-1";
}

int main() {

  cout << getPkgMngr() << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Output of this code:

```
sh: line 1: fgfgfgfg: command not found  //output from system("fdgfgfgfg")
0   //
0   //
0   // -> echo $?  outputs
1   //

pacman -Q | wc -l   // pckMngrList[i] output
```

I am aware that `int i = 1` this was for testing purposes.
I already commented the code for my own use, i hope it helps to make it easier to understand.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
system("fgfgfgfg");  //test output
cout << system("echo $?") << endl;  //test output
```

These two system() calls executes in different contexts. Therefore the output `$?` of first one can not be captured in the second one.

You can use the return value of `system()` to check if it is successful.